# Setting event handlers inside a Setter.Value structure

Tags: wpf, events, xaml, styles, setter

I have a `ListView` and i'd like to set up a context menu which i can open not only when right-clicking some text in some column but anywhere on the `ListViewItem`, to do so i thought i'd just set my `ContextMenu` using a style setter since i cannot directly access the `ListViewItem`.

Unfortunately when you try to do it like this it won't compile:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Header" Click="Handler"/>
                ...
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

> Error 102 'Handler' is not valid.
>   'Click' is not an event on
>   'System.Windows.Controls.GridView'.

I figured that you can avoid this by using an `EventSetter` for the `Click`-event. But it is apparent that the code gets quite inflated from all the wrapping tags you need.

My question is if there is some workaround so you do not have to deal with `EventSetters`.

---

**Edit:** See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5634022/546730) for an explanation on *why* this error occurs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put the `ContextMenu` in the `ListView`'s Resources and then use it as a static resource, that way you won't have to use a Style for the `MenuItem`'s

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="listViewContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Header" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource listViewContextMenu}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!--...-->
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just `ListBoxItem.HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` and then put the `ContextMenu` in your `ListBox.ItemTemplate`.  Here's an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <PointCollection x:Key="sampleData">
            <Point X="10" Y="20"/>
            <Point X="30" Y="40"/>
        </PointCollection>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox Width="100" ItemsSource="{StaticResource sampleData}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Red">
                    <Grid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Test" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry, the question says ListBox and I overlooked the other hints that it is actually a ListView.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right, totally wrote ListBox there three times, only didn't mess it up in the code since it's copied, sorry.