# How to eliminate the error "XamlParseException: Set connectionId threw an exception"?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I develop WPF Prism 6 MVVM multimodule application. Until today everything was OK. But this morning I decided to clean and rebuild my application. And after cleaning and rebuilding I have the following error when my application runs: ***System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" in PresentationFramework.dll. Set connectionId threw an exception: number of line is "5" position in line is "14"***. I've done all (clean and rebuild my application, e.t.c... in general everything that was suggested in the web to this case) but none of this helped me. You can see the error below.
[image]
What the reason of the error? How to eliminate it? Please help.

Comment: What's the exception message? What inner exceptions are there?  Have you referenced Prism correctly?

Comment: How to catch the exeption for looking the inner exception. (In particularly, I have WinDebug x86.)

Comment: XAMLParseException is not catched anywhere in the application.

Comment: I had upgraded "DevCraft" library of Telerik which I use in my application AND THE ERROR WAS ELIMINATED!

Comment: Dude, look at that exception dialog.  It has a link at the bottom to copy exception details to the clipboard.  It's right there.  Even if it's in Cyrillic (whichever flavor of language) I can still read it.  You just had reference issues.  Add an answer below with details about how you solved it and you can close this question out.

Answer (score 1):

The "Set connectionId" is a bug in the XAML code generator. Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642898/200443.

The problem can also occur if loading a Wpf related assembly fails (Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll for not naming it).