# Adding context menu to customized calendar control (WPF VB.Net)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

So I have a custom class that inherits from the stock WPF calendar, which modifies the default template with some jazz to add highlighting for certain dates, and it works great so far.

Now I'd also like to add a context menu to each dateitem button (type is CalendarDayButton). I am able to get a working context menu to come up, but when I try to add a click event it doesn't seem to fire at all.

Quick process rundown:

I have a HighlightCalendar.vb file that defines the class in my controls folder.

It is styled with a copied and modified xaml template that resides in my themes folder with filename HighlightCalendar.xaml

There is also a HighlightCalendar.xaml.vb file that resides in the themes folder. It is defined as Partial Public Class HighlightResources, and the header for my template xaml has a declared x:Class=HighlightResources.

With this setup, Visual Studio allows me to define a method name for the click event of my context menu in the properties/events tab, and creates a sub automatically with the proper header in my HighlightCalendar.xaml.vb

However, the sub is never called when I click on the context menu item. I set it to a simple MessageBox.Show("Test"), and nothing happens. Setting a breakpoint on the sub, it is never fired. Please let me know what I'm missing. Thank you.

Code Snippets:

HighlightCalendar.xaml.vb (template codebehind)

```
Partial Public Class HighlightResources
Inherits ResourceDictionary

Private Sub dayClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("test")
End Sub
End Class
```

HighlightCalendar.xaml (template)

header:

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WinSurvWPF"
    x:Class="HighlightResources">
```

Style code:

```
    <Style x:Key="HighlightCalendarDayButtonStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="test"
                          Click="dayClick"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: seems like a bug. mouseleftbuttonup and command do not work either.

Comment: I also tried the mouse enter event and nothing seems to be firing. There's nothing missing from my code, correct? It's just  a bug? This my first time using a secondary codebehind file for a custom control so I am unsure if I am doing everything correctly.

Comment: I also suspect it might be related to this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5634022/366064

Comment: That is absolutely the problem. Defining the context menu as a separate resource and referencing it separately in the template resolved all my issues. Thanks Bijan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that has to do with defining a context menu in a setter. It works properly if you define the context menu as a separate resource and then reference it in the setter.

See this link for more detail: [Why "Setting event handlers inside a Setter.Value structure" gives compilation error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5634022/366064)

Thanks to [Bijan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366064/bijan) for tracking this down for me.