# Context menu only for items in the listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I activate the context menu only for the items in the listbox?

The following will call the context menu on the whole listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="lBoxTest">
     <ListBox.ContextMenu>
           <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Name="btnTest" Header="Test" Click="btnTest_Click"/>
           </ContextMenu>
     </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way would be to set the context menu in an item container style.

```
<ListBox Name="lBoxTest">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Name="btnTest"
                                  Header="Test"
                                  Click="btnTest_Click"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

However, this might not work due to a [bug in WPF with code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634022/why-setting-event-handlers-inside-a-setter-value-structure-gives-compilation-e). It occurs due to setting an event handler in a setter value. You can mitigate this issue by declaring a separate resource for your context menu and referencing it using `StaticResource`.

```
<ListBox Name="lBoxTest">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Name="btnTest"
                      Header="Test"
                      Click="MenuItem_OnClick"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu"
                    Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This method works but now I have the problem that my click event doesn't work anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work anymore? Does the method not get called? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: Sorry, the method doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ItemsContainerStyle:

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                         <MenuItem Name="btnTest" Header="Test" />
                     </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        
</ListBox>
```