# WPF ListboxItem and ContextMenu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have code like this:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                    ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Command="Delete" Click="DeleteEvent">      
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventName}">
            </TextBlock>        
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Unfortunately It doesn't work. My context menu is disabled (it is displaying but I cannot click it because it's disabled). I've read that this problem is related to selection problem but I didn't find any solution for that. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why do you try to set the Click event and the Command of the MenuItem at the same time? Also do you want this ContextMenu to be displayed for each item or for the list? Here it is set for the whole list.

Comment: Can you be more specific or give me more details about your solution?

Comment: @Ucodia : why for the whole list? Looks like it is set inside the ListBox.ItemTemplate?

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake. I was disturbed by the fact your were laying out the ItemTemplate in a StackPanel as the ListBox will already lay out the items in a StackPanel. I will post a solution.

Comment: I want to display context menu for each ListBoxItem (I want to click with right mouse button on ListBoxItem for display menu and then select operation for example deleting ListBoxItem)

Comment: This may be because of hittesting. set a transparent background color to your stackpanel and the mouse click event mit hit the stackpanel, resulting in a visible context menu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to set Command and the Click event. You should set one or the other. Maybe the fact the action is disabled is because you are setting a Command with a value of CanExecute = false;

Instead of writing a DataTemplate, you can try to set the ItemContainerStyle for the ListBoxItem like this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="DeleteEvent"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=EventName}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Here I directly set the ContextMenu of the ListBoxItem instance so it will display the menu on the right control.

Comment: Unfortunately I got this error with your solution:
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'."}

Comment: Then maybe you should be more precise in what you are exactly trying to do with this list because this should not throw this kind of exception.

Comment: I added context menu to Resources and it's working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752273/setting-event-handlers-inside-a-setter-value-structure

Answer (score 2):

ListBox already have a MenuContext. You can try it

```
 <ListBox  x:Name="MyistBox">                      
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Update"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change command to header and handle DeleteEvent

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                        ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
                <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="DeleteEvent">      
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventName}">
                </TextBlock>        
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```