# Show ContextMenu of element in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

**Problem:**

I have a `ListBox` in which I display my data using DataBinding. The data is displayed as a custom view `SystemEnvironmentElementView`.

I want to allow the user to rename single elements. This should happen in the `ViewModel` of the desired element.

I created a `ContextMenu` in the `View` that displays my data. However when I right click on my element the `ContextMenu` is not displayed. I also encountered the problem that on my PreviewMouseDown event handler I don't get the view as `OriginalSource` in the `EventArgs` but a `Border`.

**Question:**

How do I get the ContextMenu of my element to show?

**ListBox Code:**

```
<customControls:ListBoxNoDragSelection ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" Background="{DynamicResource  BG}" SelectedItem="{Binding SystemEnviromentAnalysis.SelectedElement}"
                               BorderThickness="0" x:Name="ListBoxNoDragSelection" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedElement}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <dragAndDrop:FrameworkElementDropBehaviorWithMousePos />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="{DynamicResource MyVisualBrush}"
                        Height="Auto" Width="Auto" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Element.X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Element.Y}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="{Binding Element.Z}"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <systemEnvironment:SystemEnvironmentElementView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </customControls:ListBoxNoDragSelection>
```

**SystemEnviromentElementView:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.Editor.Views.SystemEnvironment.SystemEnvironmentElementView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Rename"/>
        </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>    
    <StackPanel>
    <Image Height="{Binding Element.Height}" Width="{Binding Element.Width}" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Element.Icon}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        <Label Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
           Content="{Binding Element.Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Where is your ContextMenu...?

Comment: ContextMenu is in SystemEnvironmentElementView but I'll edit the question to include it

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554184/wpf-listboxitem-and-contextmenu) solution worked as intended