# WPF Get content of TextBlock inside of ListView when ContextMenu clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, user-interface, contextmenu

I have a ListView which contains TextBlocks. The ListView has a context menu and I need to get the Content property of TextBlock when the context menu is clicked.

[image]

I need to get "Documents and Settings" when Download is clicked in the Context Menu.
I've tried a number of solutions, but they all result in a Null Reference Exception. Thanks!

Comment: The ListView shouldn't have the context menu, the ListViewItems should... (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554184/wpf-listboxitem-and-contextmenu while that question&answer is about ListView, it also applies in the same manner to ListView/ListViewItems.). Also, you shouldn't get the Content property of the TextBlock for the context menu, but rather the context menu should and will work with the actual data item/object represented by the Icon+TextBlock

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I setup a ItemsControl to call a command and pass in the item via a commandparameter to do some work using MVVM Light.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <h:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"></h:BindingProxy>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                     <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Remove Me" Command="{Binding Data.MyCommand, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></MenuItem>
                   </ContextMenu>
                </Grid.ContextMenu>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding SomeField}"></TextBlock>
           </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
 </Grid>
```

I use a BindingProxy to bind the window datacontext for the context menu to get the command, here is the code for that.

```
/// <summary>
/// BindingProxy
/// Used to get Parent datacontext within Child control.
/// </summary>
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region " Overrides Of Freezable "
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }
    #endregion

    #region " Data "
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

As you can see, the CommandParameter just uses {Binding} to get the object for the row of the ItemsSource which is bound to an `ObservableCollection<SomeClass>.`

Hopefully this gives you some insight into setting up a context menu to do some work.